# Is there an alternative google-apps for mail?

Tags: gmail, google-apps

Google Stops offering Google Apps for free.
Are there any alternatives to link your own domain with a good mail server as Gmail?
So registering mail provider with his own domain.

Comment: Great question - too bad a bunch o' losers closed the question

Comment: God.. Sometimes i dont understand people. Why closed this question? Move to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com dont close it -.-'

Comment: Btw Yandex coming as alternative it seems. I created 1 custom domain mail and its working. Here is page: kurum.yandex.com.tr (Turkish one, couldnt find english). I wrote an article about yandex: http://unsalkorkmaz.com/alternative-email-solution-google-apps/

Comment: FYI all, while this is a very good question, it is not appropriate for StackOverflow. This has NOTHING to do with programming or architecture. This is just as appropriate here as the question, "Where is a good place I can buy a dress with butterflies on it?" StackOverflow is specifically for programming questions, not web hosting, email hosting, or other online web sites like that.

Comment: You can add additional domains to your existing Google Apps account as a separate domain to enjoy the same Google email service as that for the primary domain. See [here](http://www.kavoir.com/2014/02/you-dont-need-a-google-apps-alternative-for-email-hosting.html). So if all you want is Gmail for your own domain, just add it as a separate domain. No need for a separate apps account or any alternatives.

Comment: i have noticed has left its motto do no harm far behind...and acting up greedier every passing month. For example: google has banned people to run server on google fiber..

Comment: A bunch of programmers are less likely to know where to buy a dress with butterflies on it than they are to know an alternative to mail from google apps.

Comment: Please note that Zoho Mail **does not offer IMAP/POP support anymore with their free plan**. Hopefully, I can save some of you debugging time with this post.
Source: https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/zoho-free-tier-pop-imap-activesync-no-longer-free

Answer (score 17):

I'm basically looking for alternatives too and so far I can only recommend Zoho Mail:

> http://www.zoho.com/mail/
>
> http://www.zoho.com/mail/zohomail-pricing.html

They have a lite version supporting 5 email accounts.

**Update**: as of 2014-11-18, Zoho's lite version now has 10 email accounts and Zoho has improved quite substantially. They now have mobile apps to access Zoho emails (very important for your technically challenged clients) and also their web interface and overall stability have improved. My recommendation for them is now stronger.

You might also want to check other paid services which are not as expensive as Google Apps:

> http://smallbusiness.yahoo.com/email/compare-plans
>
> http://www.godaddy.com/email/email-hosting.aspx

Unfortunately, I don't think you'll find something as decent and as reliable as Google Apps for a better price but if you're looking for something with less features and you need to pay less for such a service, the above might be your best options.

Cheers.

Comment: how does it scale for godaddy how many emails you can add and how is email client interface.

Comment: Looks like you can add up to 100 emails on GoDaddy. Regarding client interface, I would say Yahoo's the best, followed by Zoho, and followed by GoDaddy.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your feelings for MS, but http://domains.live.com should do what you want. Though for me I'm OK with paying to stay on Gmail vs Hotmail, personal preference only though :)

Comment: Doesn't work. Then you still need already a e-mail address with that domain.

Comment: Isn't this just for educational or similar institutions? it's not clear from their description!

Comment: You should only need an email for the initial setup if you didn't use an existing windows live account. It has been a while since I used it, but there is a tutorial at http://forum.ucoz.com/forum/37-12095-1 that shows adding new users and step by step configuration, might be worth it on a test domain.

Comment: There is Zoho too, but only allows 3 users in the free tier.